# Typescript: String literal types to differentiate another property type;

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create interface to help me with ensuring sending correct parameters to methods.

I'd like to know if it is possible to use string literal types to differentiate between expected type of values in the interface.

Something similar to interface overrides comes to mind, but I'm unable to make it work.

```
interface WhereEq {
  type: 'eq';
  value: string | number;
}

interface WhereIn {
  type: 'in';
  value: number[];
}

type Where = WhereEq | WhereIn; // obviously the union type won't work

const test: Where = {
  type: 'eq',
  value: [13] // it should throw error on trying to do that
}
```

Is it possible to do this in elegant way?

Comment: Works for me: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20WhereEq%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'eq'%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20WhereIn%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'in'%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Where%20%3D%20WhereEq%20%7C%20WhereIn%3B%20%2F%2F%20obviously%20the%20union%20type%20won't%20work%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%3A%20Where%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'eq'%2C%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20%5B13%5D%20%2F%2F%20it%20should%20throw%20error%20on%20trying%20to%20do%20that%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Why will the union type not work? It seems to raise an error as expected, see the link above

Comment: Thanks! I've must have got confused when i hovered over a value and it showed all possible types.